# Default user profile in Freeradius - How to get it to query only incoming requests that don't match a user instead of all users

Tags: freeradius

So I have a setup running Freeradius 3.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 with MariaDB SQL and Daloradius web interface. Anyhow I want to setup a default user setting to authenticate users who do not have an account setup in radius to receive an IP in an isolated network with restricted speed and access. In  the file

```
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf
```

I uncommented the line -

```
default_user_profile = "DEFAULT"
```

This enables the Default profile. I then made a entry to map the Default user to my group profile.

```
Insert into radusergroup (username, groupname, priority) VALUES ('DEFAULT', 'Default - Unauthenticated Users', '-1');
```

In the group profile 'Default - Unathenticated Users' I have the following attributes configured.

Check Attributes:

```
'Auth-Type = Accept'
```

Reply Attributes:

```
'Mikrotik_Rate-Limit := 5M/5M'
'Fall-Through = Yes'
'Framed-Pool = DHCP-Default'
```

While this is enabled it works great like I would want for my requests from MAC addresses that aren't setup with user profiles. It accepts them, assigns and IP address from my DHCP-Default pool on the DHCP server on the Mikrotik Router and it sets a cap on the upload/download speeds to 5Mbps. This however messes up my created specific user profiles Ip pool assignments and their upload/download speeds they inherit. It gets messed up because the DEFAULT user profile runs against every request. I need to somehow limit it to only requests that don't match my list of users.

Is there anything I can check in the incoming request to make it so this will only get picked up if it doesn't match an existing user profile? Or somewhere to edit a freeradius config file to adjust how the default user is applied to incoming requests so it just isn't run against everything.

I tried adjusting the priority of the group profile that the DEFAULT user points to. I have tried it as -1 to go first and 5 to go last. I was hoping this might change which group profile would get prioritized leaving off the DEFAULT settings when it matches a created user by prioritizing their group settings.

UPDATE:

I asked Chat GPT if it had any suggestions and it is recommending I do the following code in the /etc/freeradius/3.0/users file

```
authorize User {
    # Check if a matching user profile already exists
    if (User-Profile != "") {
        update request {
            User-Profile := User-Name
        }
    }
}

DEFAULT User {
  # Set a default profile if no other profile was found
  if (User-Profile == "") {
    update request {
      User-Profile := "DEFAULT"
      }
   }
}
```

On both of these sections if I comment one or the other out give the following error:

> /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/authorize[134]: Parse error
> (check) for entry authorize: Expecting operator.

I am not the greatest at scripting / coding. Does this look like a viable solution and if so what syntax is missing that would make it say it is still expecting an operator?

Answer (score 0):

The DEFAULT profile processes against all users but it processes last. So if you have an existing user it will match against their group profiles first. Then after all those are matched it runs against the DEFAULT profile and the group profiles it has. So for instance I had as group entries for a specified user the following reply attributes:

```
'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit := 250M/250M'
'Fall-Through = Yes'
'Framed-Pool := DHCP-Radius-Test'
```

And for the DEFAULT user group profile it was giving the following attributes:

```
'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit := 5M/5M'
'Fall-Through = Yes'
'Framed-Pool = DHCP-Default'
```

The line "'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit := 5M/5M'" in the DEFAULT user group profile I had to change the operator from := to only = .  The reason being that the := operator will set the attribute value of 5M even if FreeRADIUS already sees a value for Mikrotik-Rate-Limit. If you use the = operator it will only set the value for Mikrotik-Rate-Limit if it sees no value present.

So I changed my settings in the DEFAULT user profile group attribute settings to:

```
'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = 5M/5M'
'Fall-Through = Yes'
'Framed-Pool = DHCP-Default'
```

This way because they all have the = operator it will only apply the attributes if there are no other attributes seen in the reply. So this only gets picked up when the user trying to connect doesn't match any user groups that already have these settings.